# Table row is not picking up class

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML code where I draw a table and assign different classes to the Alternative rows :

```
<div id="content">
 ....
<table>
 <tr class="a1"> ... </tr>
 <tr class="a2"> ... </tr>
</table>
 ....
</div>
```

In my CSS I have the following definitions

```
#content {
    float: right;
    width: 98%;
    padding-top: 15px;

}

#content tr.a1 {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

#content tr.a2 {
    background-color: #F2FFFF;
}
```

When my HTML page loads background color remains white.

However if I update my  CSS by removing "#content" :

```
tr.a1 {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

tr.a2 {
    background-color: #F2FFFF;
}
```

everything works correctly. It seems like link to "content" property is not working. How can I fix it?
thank you in advance.

Comment: it should work, unless you have a typo or css reset (after or of an higher specifity)  else where. As is , your code works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you write `#content tr.a1` it means `tr` is right after #`content`
> which is obviously not, you have `table` in between.

I STAND CORRECTED

I have been honestly coding for 10 years wrong...

> .class1 .class2   .name1 .name2   Selects all elements with name2 that
> is a descendant of an element with name1

You can write that like this to work:
`#content * tr.a1`

or
`#content table tr.a1`

Please learn how to use [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Examples:

```css
#content {
  float: right;
  width: 98%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#content table tr.a1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#content * tr.a2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <table>
    <tr class="a1">
      <td>tr 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a2">
      <td>tr 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: "___If you write `#content tr.a1` it means `tr` is right after `#content` which is obviously not, you have `table` in between.___" This is not true. The issue in OP's question was because of not using `td` inside `tr`.  It was not anything wrong with the css.

Comment: @ikIK. Thank you  the solution and the reference.

Comment: AFAIK, using the descendant combinator (e1 e2) does not select an element in the DOM only if it's "right after" the first element. And the asterisk is the universal selector; it selects all HTML elements; it is not used as a combinator.

Comment: @vs777 I feel like noob now. Like i have been leaving under the rock all this time. I always assumed that was the case and coded it as such... I am going to delete this.

Comment: I can not delete as its accepted... @vs777 Please read this comments and my edit, also remove accepted mark.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap additionally in `<td>...</td>` tags.

Here is the correct structure for a regular table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

```css
#content {
    float: right;
    width: 98%;
    padding-top: 15px;

}

#content tr.a1 {
    color: #F1F1F1;
}

#content tr.a2 {
    color: #F2FFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <table>
   <tr class="a1">
    <td>123<td> 
   </tr>
   <tr class="a2">
    <td>123<td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. `table` without cells cannot be called a table, literally.